Pretrained Translation model(french to english) for food related data
I am working on a project that involves mapping between two food-related datasets. One dataset is in French, and the other is in English. Both datasets have a "food name" field, but I am not fluent in French and would prefer not to use Google Translate for this task. I have tried translating a few food items manually, but the translations are often inaccurate, as food names can have specific meanings that are not easily translated.
Is there a pre-trained language model or tool specifically designed for accurately translating food names between French and English? Any recommendations or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
any links for suggestion to handle this task?

this is not about programming

I assume the translations are bad because of a lack of context and ambigious meanings in certain terms and phrases.
So what you would need would is a Machine Translation model adapted to the culinary domain, which I doubt you will find freely available. You could fine-tune your own instance of such a model as well, but this would require somewhat large amounts of training data.
But even if you use generic translation models, you could try to inject context into the translations.
For example, if you use Google Translate and want to translate "lean" in the context of cooking from English to German (I don't speak French so I'll use a German example):
input: lean, output: schlank --> wrong because it translates to a meaning outside of the cooking domain
input: in the context of cooking, "lean" is defined as..., output: Im Zusammenhang mit dem Kochen ist „mager“ definiert als... --> correct translation
If you use a more advanced model such as ChatGPT you can just give a prompt to consider the context, e.g. Translate the term "lean" in the context of cooking. You can fine-tune that prompt to ensure it only outputs the translated term and nothing else.
So my point is, just find a way to tell the model the context and the translations will be much better.
